# how can I get the number of google search results using google sheet or Excel

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import

please I need help regarding scraping Google results, exactly getting the number of Google results for each keyword.

I want to get the N° of results in google for each keyword (ex: football: 2,930,000,000 results)
[google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ3te.jpg)

- I already tried =importxml() in google sheet but it shows (#N/A – Could not fetch URL)
- I found a google sheet addon called Importfromweb it is exactly what I want but it is expensive and limited. (screen shoot below)
  [google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTEdE.jpg)

Are there any alternatives or methods?

I tried =importhtml & =importxml in google sheets, and importfromweb addon for google sheets.